# Wordpress action hook

Tags: wordpress, hook, action

I have a problem with two things.
I need to add some custom logic for two processes.
First - right after inserting post (when db is updated), and second - right after updating post.

I think i need to use action hooks, but i can't find two different hooks for this operations

Answer (score 2):

Looks like "wp_insert_post_data" will work for what you need.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Also, you can try http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks as a reference.